# Сделать post/get запрос

Tags: c#, post, get

Не знаю как на шарпе сделать post/get запрос на сайте jspell.com

Суть сайта:

- Вставляем свой текст в поле и нажимаем spell check, выскакивает
     табличка где мы....
- Нажимаем очень много раз "Replace All" пока не выскочит табличка
        Spell Check Complete.
- Получаем готовый текст.

Если делать через имитацию нажатие клавиш и движение мыши то вопросов нет.

НО, как мне отправить и получить запрос в режиме post/get без имитации движений. То есть я отправляю запрос и получаю ответ в каком то string...

Comment: у них есть API?

Comment: https://tech.yandex.ru/speller/doc/dg/concepts/api-overview-docpage/

Comment: @EvgeniyZ очень интересно, спасибо!

Comment: Есть ли еще варианты только по jspell.com ????